# How to pass global variable inside php static function

Tags: php, static-classes

I am trying to pass variable on php static function. I tried this code but variable value not passed on static function. Here is my code

```
 $ses1=$_SESSION['new']['user'];
    static function simple ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    {
        $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );
        $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT ".implode(", ", self::pluck($columns, 'db'))."
             FROM $table where user = '$ses1'
             $where
             $order
             $limit"
        );
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
            "SELECT COUNT({$primaryKey})
             FROM   $table where user = '$ses1'
             $where"
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
            "SELECT COUNT({$primaryKey})
             FROM   $table where user = '$ses1'"
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];
```

Comment: _"I tried this code but variable value not passed on static function."_ - Have you tried adding a new method argument and then pass is when you call the method? Please show us how you're calling the method and explain what happens when you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call it with `global`

```
static function simple ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
{
    global $ses1;
    echo $ses1;
...
```